# if statement in a loop, python3

Tags: python, loops

I need the totals to compute...getting 0.00

Also need Residential, Business, City, and Parish to print

This is my updated code,

```
print("=========================================================")

print(format("Name", '<12s'),format("Type", '<15s'),format("Location",'<10s'),format("KwH", '<8s'),format("Total", '>8s'))

print("=========================================================")



total = 0

for i in range(10):

custName = input()

custType = input()

custLoc = input()

custKwh = eval(input())

if (custType == "R"):

    custType = "Residential"

if (custType == "B"):

    custType = "Business"

    total = (custKwh * 0.05710) + 10

if (custLoc == "C"):
    custType = "City"
    total = (custKwh * 0.0401) + 6

if (custLoc == "P"):
    custType = "Parish"
    total = (custKwh * 0.04411) + 6.60

print(format(custName, '<12s'),format(custType, '<15s'),format(custLoc, '<10s'),format(custKwh, '<8d'),format(total, '<7.2f'))
```

Comment: Im getting the inputs from a data file which inputs are R, B, C, or P

Answer (score 3):

Try using ""

```
if (custType == "R"):

    custType = Residential
```

The reason you need to put the letter in quotes is because the letter on it's own, without quotes, stands for a variable with the name that is that letter. If you put quotes around it, it literally means that letter, or word.

Comment: sweet, that seemed to have work and now im getting error: 'total' is not defined...how do I define 'total' so It computes the total cost of KwH depending on whether its City, Parish, or Business

Comment: Because I can't edit this in... The reason you need to put the letter in quotes is because the letter on it's own, without quotes, stands for a variable with the name that is that letter. If you put quotes around it, it literally means that letter, or word.

Comment: Define total right in the beginning like this total = 0.0

Comment: so I set total = 0 in the beginning and now the total is printing as 0.00, its not computing. And I am getting the letters "R, B, C, and P" instead of the words "Residential, Business, City, and Parish"

Comment: custType = "Resisdential"

Comment: Tried that before I posted and it didn't work...im stuck man and I cant get the total to compute...its printing 0.00...I also updated my whole code at the top ^

Comment: If you are getting 0.0 then your inputs are incorrect, make sure you are using uppercase

Comment: inputs are correct and I am using uppercase.